# Lubuntu Graphical Bugs

Tags: graphics, firefox, lubuntu, themes

I've Been Installed Lubuntu in Desktop and after "upgrade" some graphical/theme bugs appeared. example screenshot:

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28a8c4j&s=8#.U2uoOoaPePA]

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1316250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar bug reported in [Firefox Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1005501#c23). One of the workaround mentioned there (which works for a few people) is to set `gfx.xrender.enabled` to False in the `about:config` settings page of Firefox.

Type `about:config` in the Address Bar and search for `gfx.xrender.enabled` in the search box. Double click the item to make sure its value is False. Then restart Firefox and see if it works for you.

[image: Set gfx.xrender.enabled to false in about:config]

Comment: @bx758: [Closing a question has a different meaning on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions). The correct term would be, the question is answered to satisfaction or the answer is accepted :-)

Comment: ok sorry. question is accepted ;)